# Display Gstreamer video in QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml, gstreamer

I try to use Gstreamer(not QtGstreamer or QtMultimedia) in QML(Qt Quick Controls Application):

```
QQmlEngine engine;
   QQmlComponent component(&engine,
           QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
   QObject *object = component.create();

   QWidget *rect = (QWidget*) object->findChild<QObject*>("rectangle1");

   gst_init(NULL, NULL);

   GstElement *pipeline;
   pipeline = gst_element_factory_make("playbin", "player");

   g_object_set (G_OBJECT (pipeline), "uri", "file:///home/user/Downloads/test.mp4", NULL);

   gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
   gst_video_overlay_set_window_handle(GST_VIDEO_OVERLAY(pipeline), rect->winId());
   gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
```

But my application crashes after start. This code works fine for Qt Widgets, but problem occurs only with QML.

**So how can I display video in QML item via pure Gstreamer(not QtGstreamer or QtMultimedia)?**

P.S. Of course without backend compiling or something like this(if it possible). I think I just can use right QML item or Widget.

P.S.S I also heard about QDeclarativeItem, can I use it for this purposes? And how?

Comment: Did you run it in a debugger? You're casting objects from the qtquick engine to QWidget (`rect` - use qobject_cast instead of c-style cast), but QtQuick (2) didn't use widgets at all, so I doubt rect is valid.

Comment: QDeclarativeItem is QQ1, what you want is QQuickItem

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld many thanks for response. So can I use QQuickItem for this purposes? And can you show how can I do this?

Comment: I don’t know enough about Gstreamer tol help, but https://cgit.freedesktop.org/~hasselmm/qtquickstreamer/tree/ might help, I think there are also examples  around on how to do custom rendering with QQ items.

Comment: I think the problem here is that QML is not C (QML is basically similar to javascript), so calling GStreamer C API here will not work. Qt Widgets is C, so it works fine. Normally to use GStreamer with QML application, we need to call QtMultimedia (where GStreamer code is implement in C).

Comment: @matildagl I need to use some pipelines related to rtp, rtsp etc., so I can't use QtMultimedia. Another way is to use QtGstreamer, but can I use it on Windows, Linux, OS X, iOS, Android?

Comment: QtGstreamer sounds good. I do not use it, but searching on Google and GStreamer bugzilla show some bug-reports/questions on Windows, Android and Mac, so probably QtGstreamer support those platform